# how to select a row if multiple values are in a related table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to make a filter to find all the `stuffs` made of various `substances`.

In the database, there is:

- a `stuffs` table
- a `substances` table
- a `stuffs_substances` join table.

Now, I want to find only all the `stuffs` that are made of `gold` AND `silver` (not all the stuffs that contain gold and all stuffs that contain silver).

One last thing: the end user can type only a part of the substance name in the filter form field. For example he will type `silv` and it will show up all the stuffs made of `silver`.

So I made this query (not working):

```
select "stuffs".* 
from "stuffs" 
  inner join "stuffs_substances" as "substances_join"
    on "substances_join"."stuff_id" = "stuffs"."id" 
  inner join "substances" 
    on "substances_join"."substance_id" = "substances"."id" 
where ("substances"."name" like '%silv%') 
and ("substances"."name" like '%gold%')
```

It returns an empty array. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you just want aggregation:

```
select st.*
from "stuffs" st join
     "stuffs_substances" ss join
     on ss."stuff_id" = st."id" join
     "substances" s
     on ss."substance_id" = s."id" 
where s."name" like '%silv%' or 
      s."name" like '%gold%'
group by st.id
having count(*) filter (where s."name" like '%silv%') > 0 and
       count(*) filter (where s."name" like '%gold%') > 0;
```

Note that this works, assuming that `stuff.id` is the primary key in `stuffs`.

I don't understand your fascination with double quotes and long table aliases.  To me, those things just make the query harder to write and to read.

Comment: thank you. double quotes and long table aliases where generated by knex.js

Answer (score 0):

if you want to do search by part of word then do action to re-run query each time user write a letter of word , and the filter part in query in case of oracle sql way 
in case to search with start part only

```
where name like :what_user_write || '%'
```

or in case any part of word

```
where name like '%' || :what_user_write || '%'
```

you can also use CAB, to be sure user can search by capital or small whatever

Comment: Hello @M. Zaky. Welcome to SO. in my question is not about re-running the query. please re-read. there is a join table and the `stuff` needs to have `substances` in that related table.

Answer (score -1):

ok, you ask about join, I test this in     `mysql` , it work find to get stuff made from gold and silver or silver and so on, hope this help

```
select sf.id, ss.code, sf.stuff_name from stuffs sf, stuffs_substances ss , substances s
where sf.id = ss.id
and  s.code = ss.code
and s.sub_name like  'gol%'
```

Comment: you should stop using the old, ancient and fragile implicit joins in the `WHERE` clause and start using an explicit `JOIN` operator.

Comment: ok,                                                                                                                        select sf.id, ss.code, sf.stuff_name from stuffs sf 
join stuffs_substances ss ON sf.id = ss.id
join  substances s ON s.code = ss.code
where s.sub_name like  'gol%'